# Count cells with shown data (ignores hidden values)

Tags: excel

I would like to achieve this in MS Excel:

[image]

[image]

I have tried to insert =SUBTOTAL(103,C5:C23) into $C$4, but it returns 19 before filter and 5 after filter.

Anyone has any idea? Thanks!

PS: Empty cells in $C$5:$C$23 ="" based on formula in each cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this in cell C4:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUBTOTAL(103,OFFSET(C5:C23,ROW(C5:C23)-MIN(ROW(C5:C23)),,1))*(C5:C23<>""))
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Excel Hero. Again, you're a genius!